long group with many categories in gglikert in R
i have a data frame with 3 columns of likert level values and a column grouping with many categories. For presenttation purposes i made letters level from A to Z (but ignore it please because the real life data set has other more complicated character values).
The question is : How can i pass all this categories in "?" space code in order to plot this likert chart ?


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggstats)


set.seed(123)
likert_levels <- c(
  "1" = "Very  Dissatisfied",
  "2" = "Dissatisfied",
  "3" = "Neutral",
  "4" = "Satisfied",
  "5" = "Very  Satisfied")
df = data.frame(
  var = sample(LETTERS, 50, replace = TRUE),
  A = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),
  C = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.factor))%>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(across(-var, ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))
mutate(df, id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, var), names_to="group") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=var)%>%
  ggstats::gglikert( "?", 
           facet_rows=vars(group))




Do you want ggstats::gglikert(-c(id, group), facet_rows = vars(group))?

@stefan write it as an answer it as answer.But if the var column had one category and not  26 ?

Similar to tidyverse verbs gglikert allows to use tidy-select syntax to select the columns to include=, i.e. instead of providing the columns to include you can provide the columns to exclude using - or !. And referring to your comment, this also works when there is only one var column:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(ggstats)

mutate(df, id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, var), names_to = "group") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var) %>%
  ggstats::gglikert(-c(id, group), facet_rows = vars(group))


